# Start root activity if no other activity live for this android app when press back key

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a message notification, when user select the notificaton, a message display activity will show.

When user read the message and press back key to close the activity, I want to check if the previous activity is the same app's, if so, just go ahead, if not, I want to start the home activity for this app.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

How about this: Have the notification launch the Home Activity in a state that immediately has the Home Activity launch the MessageDisplayActivity.  That is:  (1) The intent that the notification sends should target the HomeActivity and include an extra flag identifying the Intent as being from the notification.  (2) The HomeActivity, in onCreate(), upon finding that flag then simply launches the MesssageDisplayActivity.

Thus the HomeActivity will exist for a brief moment of time, but probably not long enough to be visible.  It will then remain upon the back stack so that the back key will bring you there.

Comment: In that case, the home activity should not be marked as "singleTask", I think, if the app is running in some stage, and then user select the notification, viewed the message, pressed back key to the home activity, all other works the person with is lost.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider changing the [launch mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) of your `Activity`, so that you never have this problem - using `singleTask` or `singleInstance` should make this `Activity` always be the only one open for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Have Intents within your app that call the message display activity (MDA) pass a boolean value of "true" that's extracted and stored in a field in the MDA. Have the field set by default to "false." Thus, if the MDA is called from an activity within your app, the field will have a boolean value of "true," if it's called from anywhere else (such as a notification), it will be set to false.

Override public void onBackPressed() in the MDA as follows:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (wasCalledFromYourApp == true) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        //[code that launches your app's home activity here]
    }
}
```

(This is assuming the notification will only be created by one app).